# Warning: Selector got both text and root, root is being ignored

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote a scrapy spider that was working as normal, but suddenly started getting this warning:

`/home/user/github-repos/scrapper/scrapper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py:83: UserWarning: Selector got both text and root, root is being ignored. super().__init__(text=text, type=st, root=root, **kwargs)`

Upon further inspection, the section which produces the error is the following

```
    __slots__ = ["response"]
    selectorlist_cls = SelectorList

    def __init__(self, response=None, text=None, type=None, root=None, **kwargs):
        if response is not None and text is not None:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{self.__class__.__name__}.__init__() received "
                "both response and text"
            )

        st = _st(response, type)

        if text is not None:
            response = _response_from_text(text, st)

        if response is not None:
            text = response.text
            kwargs.setdefault("base_url", response.url)

        self.response = response
        super().__init__(text=text, type=st, root=root, **kwargs)
```

The warning specifies that the root is being ignored, even though the constructor requires it. This is a class within the scrapy package so it may relate to an update on their behalf.

This is the only part of my code that interacts with selectors:

```
    def load_item(self, response: TextResponse, app_id, db_id, urls):
        loader = AppLoader(response=response)
        loader.add_value("app_id", app_id)
        loader.add_value("db_id", db_id)
        loader.add_value("url", response.url)
        loader.add_css("game_title", "#appHubAppName::text")
        loader.add_css("publisher", "#game_highlights .dev_row+ .dev_row a::text")
        loader.add_css("developer", "#developers_list a::text")
        loader.add_css("publish_date", ".date::text")
        loader.add_css("tags", "#glanceCtnResponsiveRight a::text")
        loader.add_css(
            "review_count", "#review_type_all+ label .user_reviews_count::text"
        )
        loader.add_css(
            "positive_review_count",
            "#review_type_positive+ label .user_reviews_count::text",
        )
        loader.add_css(
            "negative_review_count",
            "#review_type_negative+ label .user_reviews_count::text",
        )
        loader.add_value("file_urls", urls)

        return loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @limg21 How do you solved this problem? 
I get the same warning message raised in the parsel selector class (https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/master/parsel/selector.py). Even if I just try the pure `quotes` example from the tutorial in the scrapy docs, I get this warning message when a css or xpath selector is called, like: `response.css('div.quote')`
Can anybody this confirm?

Comment: Did not solve it yet. I plan to disable the warning till a solution is found, not the best approach tough @Mike42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are changes in the dependency package `parsel` (https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/master/parsel/selector.py) in version 1.8.1. (with commit 3b3ec90) compared to version 1.7.0
In the `__init__` of `class Selector` the kwarg `root: Optional[Any] = None` was changed to `root: Optional[Any] = _NOT_SET`

The `class Selector` in the `scrapy`package (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/unified.py) provides `root=None` by default to the super class in the `parsel` package.
This causes that warning message in the `__init__` of `class Selector` in the `parsel` package.
I will open an issue there.

Comment: Not the solution but this explains it

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to scrapy 2.9.0 solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5913 issue about this problem

this warning is harmless

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem was before. And that is because of one element of my xpath miss  Quotation Mark.